# Adding to Magento Category Menu Fails

Tags: event-observer, menu, class

we're working with a class which should be placing groups and pages into the top menu of our magento shop, however it doesn't seem to be functioning.

From what I can see first the observer is created in the module.

```
<events>
    <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
        <observers>
            <attributeSplash>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>attributeSplash/observer</class>
                <method>injectTopmenuLinksObserver</method>
            </attributeSplash>
        </observers>
    </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
</events>
```

As it's an obsererver will it be theme dependant? Can anyone suggest where we might be going wrong?

Then in the observer the menu is called based on the pages or groups.

```
class Fishpig_AttributeSplash_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Inject links into the top navigation
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function injectTopmenuLinksObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   
        if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('attributeSplash/navigation/enabled')) {
            $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('attributeSplash/group_collection')
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addOrderByName()
                ->load();

            $this->_injectLinks($groups, $observer->getEvent()->getMenu());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Inject links into the top navigation
     *
     * @param Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract $items
     * @param Varien_Data_Tree_Node $parentNode
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _injectLinks($items, $parentNode)
    {
        if (!$parentNode) {
            return false;   
        }

        foreach($items as $item) {
            if (!$item->canIncludeInMenu()) {
                continue;
            }

            $children = $item->getSplashPages();

            if ($children && count($children->addOrderByName()->addFieldToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)->load()) === 0) {
                continue;
            }

            $data = array(
                'name' => $item->getName(),
                'id' => $item->getMenuNodeId(),
                'url' => $item->getUrl(),
                'is_active' => $item->isActive(),
            );

            if ($data['is_active']) {
                $parentNode->setIsActive(true);
                $buffer = $parentNode;

                while($buffer->getParent()) {
                    $buffer = $buffer->getParent();
                    $buffer->setIsActive(true);
                }
            }

            $itemNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $parentNode->getTree(), $parentNode);
            $parentNode->addChild($itemNode);

            if ($children) {
                $this->_injectLinks($children, $itemNode);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed any ideas where the problem may lie please?

Comment: Define  "it doesn't seem to be functioning". What is the problem? Is the observer called?

Comment: Thankyou for your reply Marius. Is there a way to test whether the observer is called? I have just started working with Magento so I'm a little inexperienced!

Comment: Try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/146